# Show string from the beginning React Native TextInput

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have a problem when showing the value from a `TextInput`, currently it is showing the last part of the string. i.e, given the following string `1 - This is a pretty long string` it shows `ong string` instead of `1 - This is`.

I've tried passing `selection` as a prop but it doesn't work as expected. It only "accommodates" the string when the input is focused again.

```
selection={{start:0, end:0}}
```

PS: I do not want to truncate the string, just show the start.

Here is my Input (this is the one from NativeBase but it does have the same props than TextInput from ReactNative)

```
        <Input
          ref={getRef}
          testID={`input-${testID}`}
          value={value}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          style={styles.input}//this styling is only for fontSize/color
          onFocus={onFocus}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
```

Comment: You mean you have a string before you type it, and you want to add it to it?

Comment: Nope. Just imagine that the string is longer that the TextInput field. You won't see the entire string, it will hide the beginning of the string but I want it to hide the end of the string.

Comment: have you found any solution fir this?

Answer (score 0):

define a state called selection like

```
type selection = {
  start: number;
  end: number;
};

const [selected, setSelected] = useState<selection>({
  start: 0,
  end: 0,
  });
```

and onFocus set your selection state as

```
setSelected({
      start: address.length,
      end: address.length,
    });
```